# r glmmLasso : Error in n %*% s (glmm.rmd#64): requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Tags: r, statistics, glm, mixed-models, lasso-regression

I am trying to fit a glmmLasso model using this code:

```
lasso <- glmmLasso(stars ~ ADJRIND + AUC + KAPPA + DICE + ICCORR + JACRD + MUTINF +  RNDIND + SURFOVLP + SURFDICE + VOLSMTY + HDRFDST + AVGDIST + MAHLNBS + VARINFO + GCOERR + PROBDST + SNSVTY + SPCFTY + PRCISON + RECALL + FMEASR + ACURCY + FALLOUT + TP + FP + TN + FN + GTVOL + SEGVOL, rnd = ~1|participant, family = acat(), data = mixedModel_df, lambda=10, switch.NR=TRUE, control=list(print.iter=TRUE))
```

I get the following error msg:

```
Error in n %*% s (glmm.rmd#64): requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

all the IVs and my DV are doubles, only my random variable is a factor.

Also what should I specify for family?

As I requested here the head of my dataframe:

```
"","condition","algorithm","patient","participant","stars","ADJRIND","AUC","KAPPA","DICE","ICCORR","JACRD","MUTINF","RNDIND","SURFOVLP","SURFDICE","VOLSMTY","HDRFDST","AVGDIST","MAHLNBS","VARINFO","GCOERR","PROBDST","SNSVTY","SPCFTY","PRCISON","RECALL","FMEASR","ACURCY","FALLOUT","TP","FP","TN","FN","GTVOL","SEGVOL"
"1","rnd","BIIPL-rnd","brats_2013_pat0116_1","ablaze_gull",3,0.756964689377408,0.926221010756581,0.768802263900468,0.776064818441724,0.768315078860883,0.65050064332349,0.135475119060726,0.971161689934318,0.874015774267621,0.887817577382146,0.866059384942721,14.6242696243608,0.938245742350098,0.293565667284625,0.160520618779326,0.0249053133772558,0.334382929069828,0.861652251473578,0.990789770039584,0.744264326384239,0.861652251473578,0.776064818441724,0.985270803169769,0.00921022996041633,669.333333333333,198.222222222222,20804.6666666667,131.444444444444,800.777777777778,867.555555555556
"2","simple","simple","brats_2013_pat0116_1","ablaze_gull",6,0.864182045030138,0.954469433017555,0.870656560504094,0.874123730811541,0.870654729849903,0.779756022847205,0.164077165463804,0.986913573761583,0.974186271807427,0.979900170507277,0.957512050579079,6.97899055058698,0.175777792477891,0.114795641459174,0.0924422799237813,0.0125654163033296,0.147516600257771,0.913391157391641,0.99554770864347,0.839991365397643,0.913391157391641,0.874123730811541,0.99340680392773,0.00445229135652993,749.333333333333,92.4444444444444,20910.4444444444,51.4444444444444,800.777777777778,841.777777777778
"3","zyx","zyx","brats_2013_pat0116_1","ablaze_gull",5,0.870755923933255,0.952679073225429,0.876764151799132,0.879962617937312,0.876762586811393,0.78886242309958,0.165135328034368,0.98790705513673,0.981797036327553,0.980082675921329,0.964137575847861,7.45373777515636,0.172965178585364,0.102381275486303,0.0869596431464502,0.0116484532775206,0.139556099413398,0.909124934179681,0.996233212271177,0.855306841266058,0.909124934179681,0.879962617937312,0.993911405460269,0.00376678772882303,746,78.8888888888889,20924,54.7777777777778,800.777777777778,824.888888888889
"4","rnd","NJIT4321-rnd","brats_2013_pat0130_1","ablaze_gull",4.66666666666667,0.85306228612433,0.950463081424465,0.860901046931854,0.865114219533763,0.860857546901481,0.765289506462121,0.165902118593191,0.983989082060977,0.976890577030139,0.974069012629503,0.90775738368346,4.81983416902026,0.180602636858228,0.11416432081964,0.104953444577379,0.0149408163861948,0.15932446284558,0.905340924248747,0.995585238600183,0.849506729173741,0.905340924248747,0.865114219533763,0.991917129836001,0.00441476139981669,725.222222222222,89.2222222222222,20432.4444444444,81.1111111111111,806.333333333333,814.444444444444
"5","simple","simple","brats_2013_pat0130_1","ablaze_gull",5.33333333333333,0.85114266479814,0.948252440431362,0.858939084118719,0.863141736009654,0.858899132291815,0.762269269811805,0.165170605240332,0.984029969073529,0.978056597734505,0.975025528879729,0.910458708845115,4.24374989738083,0.179670438458937,0.107656330926193,0.104676641737853,0.0148917217218999,0.161945633247734,0.900627942177379,0.995876938685345,0.848419539019799,0.900627942177379,0.863141736009654,0.991938377123562,0.00412306131465471,719.888888888889,83.5555555555556,20438.1111111111,86.4444444444444,806.333333333333,803.444444444444
"6","zyx","zyx","brats_2013_pat0130_1","ablaze_gull",5,0.852937839717816,0.946405048878467,0.860405209999464,0.864421349815021,0.860343196696214,0.765679742754649,0.167425516242723,0.984621691861738,0.992079844226351,0.975692379970523,0.886529546039636,5.87456263780313,0.190822351731851,0.110378761504372,0.0990425203771905,0.0141114720044004,0.162026913526487,0.896740018774269,0.996070078982665,0.864244423545339,0.896740018774269,0.864421349815021,0.992240792064425,0.00392992101733526,722.333333333333,79.2222222222222,20442.4444444444,84,806.333333333333,801.555555555556
"7","rnd","UTintelligence-rnd","brats_2013_pat0134_1","ablaze_gull",1,0.439786545572739,0.734625155724745,0.465756360468916,0.488884490908871,0.46288397904837,0.347261286186172,0.104377530895259,0.907741141155794,0.765389141177261,0.654499477639931,0.696681027725238,21.7259079503732,2.41851089469065,0.46886831548909,0.401259375354614,0.0738450010093984,1.33323405520428,0.492371538620209,0.976878772829282,0.594188643079343,0.492371538620209,0.488884490908871,0.951254405933036,0.0231212271707184,736.444444444444,481.777777777778,19740.8888888889,574.555555555556,1311,1218.22222222222
"8","simple","simple","brats_2013_pat0134_1","ablaze_gull",3.33333333333333,0.785524625502044,0.901316639398279,0.801388538397059,0.810880384656072,0.801313556069467,0.696584302979966,0.207963331040685,0.965077426818364,0.958667243569809,0.928427262204787,0.916562197208537,12.6546214655814,0.472279577962782,0.107353421791921,0.197743216013271,0.0320484916833766,0.26517778145634,0.809476686023845,0.993156592772713,0.824707032687797,0.809476686023845,0.810880384656072,0.982142000911457,0.0068434072272868,1066.88888888889,141.222222222222,20081.4444444444,244.111111111111,1311,1208.11111111111
"9","zyx","zyx","brats_2013_pat0134_1","ablaze_gull",5.33333333333333,0.808816961290452,0.915389573957884,0.82255657191667,0.830680387649496,0.822524512693832,0.724253190335505,0.22263294830665,0.969975154484348,0.968502955091587,0.936460323238279,0.935112385680564,14.3628067945127,0.484728125133601,0.0985229007138266,0.177639450016539,0.0279718268170166,0.229407179518171,0.837724911061577,0.99305423685419,0.832290331137827,0.837724911061577,0.830680387649496,0.984701258781098,0.00694576314580967,1122.22222222222,144.555555555556,20078.1111111111,188.777777777778,1311,1266.77777777778
"10","rnd","Misfits-rnd","brats_2019_138_1","ablaze_gull",3,0.516106062592575,0.873715987224171,0.523038256992382,0.527656540346325,0.521661240623707,0.432121538305335,0.101222815104127,0.977103022412987,0.620103370493099,0.650702373280009,0.601390174958572,19.2537294363992,3.56344098531587,0.742348348696815,0.118109524669584,0.017378193265862,10.1585752147551,0.754093369661688,0.993338604786654,0.503577431529888,0.754093369661688,0.527656540346325,0.988377655513698,0.00666139521334549,447.111111111111,136.666666666667,20606,97.8888888888889,545,583.777777777778
"11","simple","simple","brats_2019_138_1","ablaze_gull",3.66666666666667,0.706452946686834,0.864953464263324,0.708649608736678,0.709924711751815,0.708580745993345,0.612548925090868,0.126104497349992,0.994785970651161,0.89537673459454,0.822033177974469,0.779958731884256,19.8501973757616,2.61846276424863,0.467761562013242,0.0385223535652684,0.00460614018952978,0.716819072659924,0.730891949753302,0.999014978773347,0.814645168472805,0.730891949753302,0.709924711751815,0.997383637222852,0.000985021226653005,510.777777777778,19.3333333333333,20723.3333333333,34.2222222222222,545,530.111111111111
"12","zyx","zyx","brats_2019_138_1","ablaze_gull",3.66666666666667,0.610753810401177,0.779712151049051,0.612727017856821,0.613869106450475,0.612524486488184,0.551363347584298,0,0.994766944943347,0,0.676414733802843,0.632006181002577,32.7153630434273,5.88313878476988,0.904099638796773,0,0.103402624869185,0.195759812968779,0.559908770106544,0.999515531991557,0.743154734248098,0.559908770106544,0.613869106450475,0.997373332439284,0.000484468008443052,500.444444444444,9.33333333333333,20733.3333333333,44.5555555555556,545,509.777777777778
"13","rnd","jaguars-rnd","brats_2019_141_1","ablaze_gull",4.33333333333333,0.776798511092125,0.9317995657587,0.788648121769615,0.795339119656737,0.788418290173286,0.679887517482747,0.196866342094433,0.974220482589075,0.872334990138839,0.900384822932791,0.847074704404622,16.5906961635536,0.919603987391872,0.123497536657694,0.155282955291875,0.023063324485323,0.298026651717319,0.870914581312203,0.992684550205198,0.777214433083584,0.870914581312203,0.795339119656737,0.986931119159787,0.00731544979480233,882.888888888889,136.555555555556,18413.5555555556,120.333333333333,1003.22222222222,1019.44444444444
"14","simple","simple","brats_2019_141_1","ablaze_gull",5,0.835890266663824,0.90833613741848,0.8426182511776,0.846277863042727,0.842552946270031,0.760738977047531,0.217793633127813,0.986032615479199,0.968525544930771,0.950089365515111,0.922774534238376,9.02494724371663,0.365712977970675,0.147826375535477,0.0979926364847341,0.0130304763502148,0.233237811437155,0.819784468248017,0.996887806588943,0.895772876952561,0.819784468248017,0.846277863042727,0.992962414786454,0.00311219341105724,923.111111111111,56.6666666666667,18493.4444444444,80.1111111111111,1003.22222222222,979.777777777778
"15","zyx","zyx","brats_2019_141_1","ablaze_gull",5,0.806421117677648,0.884725093453355,0.81387284154689,0.817936172710702,0.813668896379885,0.731083455431912,0.211748115057157,0.984046725668933,0.990145970199641,0.916421870155159,0.863140738937082,8.49706824661522,0.499082439574537,0.211907909066182,0.10400475182111,0.0143409339546113,0.336382757538914,0.772799817859347,0.996650369047362,0.917527401034257,0.772799817859347,0.817936172710702,0.991951857957291,0.00334963095263752,906,60.3333333333333,18489.7777777778,97.2222222222222,1003.22222222222,966.333333333333
"16","rnd","FightGliomas-rnd","brats_2019_90_1","ablaze_gull",6,0.968257954413161,0.987093362528072,0.970800193935607,0.972048533746708,0.970801355739778,0.94570310089342,0.204682906269684,0.995299728580093,0.99851769262895,0.99773209120061,0.990706184810191,2.35337109861099,0.0344489741039471,0.0285055152008294,0.0397278812479393,0.00464629073617492,0.0288059740714348,0.975754720290816,0.998432004765327,0.9685629127278,0.975754720290816,0.972048533746708,0.997641026050083,0.00156799523467276,770.222222222222,30.7777777777778,20064.1111111111,18.5555555555556,788.777777777778,801
"17","simple","simple","brats_2019_90_1","ablaze_gull",5.66666666666667,0.952329476723764,0.982446168742101,0.955913951405959,0.957702789853,0.955915379517709,0.918920095273011,0.198412758997542,0.993254294603284,0.9948496225819,0.995843213411434,0.981882531870561,3.4166433002747,0.0553223101655522,0.0321278128256843,0.0537364283831558,0.00663399526436313,0.0442181038384758,0.967137999982214,0.997754337501988,0.949079574914114,0.967137999982214,0.957702789853,0.996610565192861,0.00224566249801225,762.111111111111,44.4444444444444,20050.4444444444,26.6666666666667,788.777777777778,806.555555555556
"18","zyx","zyx","brats_2019_90_1","ablaze_gull",5.66666666666667,0.957669116253882,0.985320290447796,0.960897795289467,0.962499846465236,0.960898699250652,0.927832221824958,0.201587609349249,0.993957447335076,0.998264235195115,0.996885441695005,0.977337562590699,3.15931022051951,0.0457814118164736,0.025446184952602,0.0483538818641294,0.00592110152408344,0.0390370747623204,0.972853877376545,0.997786703519048,0.953321254089481,0.972853877376545,0.962499846465236,0.996965340044328,0.00221329648095196,769,43.7777777777778,20051.1111111111,19.7777777777778,788.777777777778,812.777777777778
"19","rnd","Tyagi-rnd","brats_MDA_945_1","ablaze_gull",4.33333333333333,0.745555569694423,0.885669742953136,0.759263828544658,0.767838981407406,0.759157345204569,0.633507916050858,0.146023656683058,0.967517603171903,0.881010728788507,0.88835140017712,0.910730480827375,12.3514245536757,0.815941012416867,0.280601413840585,0.188352804604093,0.0295388388785871,0.328332764553787,0.78016854749535,0.991170938410922,0.772205515354681,0.78016854749535,0.767838981407406,0.983443927479636,0.00882906158907816,717.111111111111,180.111111111111,20582.4444444444,175.666666666667,892.777777777778,897.222222222222
"20","simple","simple","brats_MDA_945_1","ablaze_gull",5.33333333333333,0.826356297027293,0.916198592408247,0.836785251821064,0.842660724647247,0.836755885662414,0.731791097441842,0.169311412198244,0.977814120503358,0.967413416696995,0.953399039161258,0.933051000360542,7.68751024370488,0.267137250532801,0.106993910988983,0.141276068501097,0.0208114845989645,0.191602981147392,0.838959573262704,0.993437611553791,0.857374950750217,0.838959573262704,0.842660724647247,0.98876460334073,0.00656238844620888,785.555555555556,131.888888888889,20630.6666666667,107.222222222222,892.777777777778,917.444444444444
```

*edit*

I somehow got a calculation running now by reducing some predictors and switching the family variable and getting rid of my random variables for the moment:

```
glm3 <- glmmLasso(stars ~ ADJRIND + AUC + KAPPA + DICE + ICCORR + JACRD + MUTINF +  RNDIND + SURFOVLP + SURFDICE + VOLSMTY + HDRFDST + AVGDIST + MAHLNBS + VARINFO + GCOERR + PROBDST + SNSVTY + SPCFTY + PRCISON + RECALL + FMEASR + ACURCY + FALLOUT, rnd = NULL, family = cumulative(), data = mixedModel_df, lambda=10, switch.NR=TRUE, control=list(print.iter=TRUE))
```

However the calculation is stuck at iteration 89 for 30minutes now.
I have trouble deciding which one is the correct family type for my problem. This question is probably better suited for CV. How do I correctly specify my random variables, my final model will have two?

Comment: What does your outcome variable ("stars") represent?

Comment: it is a metric variable with values between 1.0 and 6.0.

Comment: My predictors wich are heavily intercorrelated. So I was hopping Lasso could help me to reduce the amount of them.

Comment: Could you provide a small data example that produces the error you show above?

Comment: @ekstroem done, see above :)

Comment: hmm reading more about the subject it seems glmmLasso is for ordinal dependant variables why I would argue that mine is quasi-metric?